# Java Insert Query With TextFields issue

Tags: java, database, swing

I'm making a GUI. Which can insert data when user click `JButton b1`. The back-end database has 1 table which is movies and has two columns.The name of 1st column is `title` and data type is `varchar` and 2nd column name is `year` which has data type `integer`.But i don't know how to write this query in program with the help of text fields. I try many codes on query but nothing happend.
Code:

```
public class A extends JFrame{

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JLabel l1;
    private JLabel l2;
    private JButton b1;

    private  Connection conn;
    private Statement state;
    String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo";
    String user="root";
    String pass="65";

    public A(){
        super("Query");

        setLayout(null);

        t1= new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(173, 152, 128, 27);
        add(t1);

        //for year
        t2= new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(173, 105, 128, 27);
        add(t2);


        l1= new JLabel("title");
        l1.setBounds(99, 101, 42, 37);
        add(l1);

        l1= new JLabel("year");
        l1.setBounds(99, 148, 42, 37);
        add(l1);

        b1= new JButton("Insert");
        b1.setBounds(50, 222, 102, 37);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{

            CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"') "); 



                }
                catch(Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        setSize(450,450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public void CreateQuery(String w){
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(server,user,pass);
             state =  conn.createStatement();
             state.executeUpdate(w);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed");
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
}
}
```

Comment: send the stack trace or error..

Comment: Parse the String to integer `Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());` and use it in query

Comment: @Madhan can you give me proper code of parseInt

Comment: That is the [properCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, First one is the procedure you are using, i.e. using createStatement

In your case you have to set both title and year.

```
CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"', " + t2.getText() + ")");
```

And the second one is using preparedStatement,
Method calling,

```
CreateQuery(t1.getText(), t2.getText());
```

Method,

```
public void CreateQuery(String title, String year){
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(server,user,pass);
             PreparedStatement state =  conn.prepareStatement("insert into movies (title,year) values('?', ?)");
             state.setString(1, title);
             state.setInt(1, new Integer(year));
             state.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed");
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: error come on click For input String "Record" when i type this on t1 textfield

Comment: Please specify the error you are receiving. You can solve the problem by easily running query directly. First, output the query in console and then copy the output and run it directly. For example, System.out.println(query); before the exception occurs. And please specify the exception you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

You have `insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"')`  you need two parameters and you are sending only one.

---**Edit**---

Replace `Statement`  by `PreparedStatement` and use parameters with the `setInt` and `setString` methods. It is a good practice check the following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: yes but if you write in the JTextField t1 the value "Clockwork Orange" the query that is going to be executed is insert into movies (title,year) values('Clockwork Orange') and you need something like this insert into movies (title,year) values('Clockwork Orange',2009)  so you need to modify it for something like this CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"',"+t2.getText()+") ");

Answer (score 0):

By sending two argument that is the title & year may solve the problem

Modified code

```
CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"',"+t2.getText()+") ");
```

if you have any default value is there for the year field then, below is the modified code.

```
CreateQuery("insert into movies (title) values('"+t1.getText()+"') ");
```

Comment: But back-end data type of second column is integer

Comment: varchar values need single quotes. And here the number field which was returned as string can be passed as it is (but a string formed by numbers).

Comment: String q = t2.getText();
int w = Integer.parseInt(q);
try{
CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"',"+w+") "); i try this but it didn't work

Comment: in this case   **int w = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());**  //will work fine (or) **String w = t2.getText();** //will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
b1= new JButton("Insert");
        b1.setBounds(50, 222, 102, 37);
        add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


                try{
int w = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());

CreateQuery("insert into movies (title,year) values('"+t1.getText()+"',"+w+") ");                   


    }
                catch(Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception Error on Click

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "World"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Queryahmad.C_03Update$1.actionPerformed(C_03Update.java:76)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```